# Cannot read properties of null (read 'connect') when trying to trigger Twilio Conference Voice Call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio

Working on creating a function that receives an object. This object contains key, value pairs of usernames.

I iterate through the key value pairs and for each pair, create a Twilio Conference Room topic, I assign key+value to this topic name

Inside the for loop, I add each pair as a participant in a Twilio Conference Room, create a conference room for each and presumably redirect each pair to their respective conference rooms.

However, the intended action of redirecting each pair to their respective Twilio Conference rooms is not occurring. I instead get the errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'connect')
```

I initially start off by creating a device object in a previous component:

```
 const setupTwilio = (nickname) => {
 fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/voice_chat/token/${nickname}`)
 .then(response => console.log('setupTwilio returns: ',response.json()))
 .then(data => {
 const twilioToken = JSON.parse(data).token;
 const device = new Device(twilioToken);
 device.updateOptions(twilioToken, {
 codecPreferences: ['opus', 'pcmu'],
 fakeLocalDTMF: true,
 maxAverageBitrate: 16000,
 maxCallSignalingTimeoutMs: 30000
 });
 device.on('error', (device) => {
 console.log("error: ", device)
 });
 setState({... state, device, twilioToken, nickname})
 })
 .catch((error) => {
 console.log(error)
 })
 };

const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const nickname = user.username;
    setupTwilio(nickname);
    const rooms = state.rooms;
    updateWaitingRoomStatus()
    setState((state) => {
        return {...state, rooms }
    });
    sendWaitingRoomUsersToRedisCache()
    history.push('/rooms');
}
```

From here the user then navigates to the next component/page. This is the waiting room. In this component, a useEffect creates said room and redirects each pair:

```
useEffect((() => {
        handleRoomCreate()
    }), [availableOnlineUsers])
const createRoomHandler = (curr,matched) => {
        const userData = {'roomName': curr+matched, 'participantLabel': [curr, matched] }
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/voice_chat/rooms', userData )
            .then(res => {
                console.log('axios call has been hit', res.data)
            })
    }
    const handleRoomCreate = () => {
        for ( let [k, v] of new Map( Object.entries(randomizeAndMatch(availableOnlineUsers.current)))){
                const createdRoomTopic = k+v
                setState({ ...state, createdRoomTopic})
                const selectedRoom = {
                    room_name: state.createdRoomTopic, participants: [k,v]
                };
                setState({ ...state, selectedRoom})
                const rooms = state.rooms;
                const roomId = rooms.push(selectedRoom)
                createRoomHandler(k,v);
                history.push(`/rooms/${roomId}`)
            }
    }
```

Here is a sample of the data I get from `randomizeAndMatch(availableOnlineUsers.current)`, the function that returns an object with pairs of users:

```
{testingUser: 'emmTest', testing22: 'AnotherUser'}
```

This is the `voice_chat/rooms` API endpoint:

```
...
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        room_name = request.POST.get("roomName", "default")
        participant_label = request.POST.get("participantLabel", "default")
        response = VoiceResponse()
        dial = Dial()
        dial.conference(
            name=room_name,
            participant_label=participant_label,
            start_conference_on_enter=True,
        )
        print(dial)
        response.append(dial)
        return HttpResponse(response.to_xml(), content_type="text/xml")
```

I know the above view works when it comes to creating a conference call and presume I wouldn't have to make any changes to this view to create multiple conference calls since I would be iteratively posting to this endpoint

The error appears to point to this `Rooms`, specifically that there is no room_name in state? In `Rooms` I grab the selectedRoom room_name from state

```
const roomName = state.selectedRoom.room_name;
useEffect(() => {
        const params = {
            roomName: roomName, participantLabel: nickname
        };
        if (!call) {
            const callPromise = device.connect({ params });
            callPromise.then((call) => {
                setCall(call);
            });
        }
```

I do this because I need params to actually start the conference call. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Realized I wasn't resolving the promise and creating a device object

Removing the console log I had in my setupTwilio function resolved this:

```
const setupTwilio = (nickname) => {
    fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/voice_chat/token/${nickname}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        const twilioToken = JSON.parse(data).token;
        const device = new Device(twilioToken);
        device.updateOptions(twilioToken, {
            codecPreferences: ['opus', 'pcmu'],
            fakeLocalDTMF: true,
            maxAverageBitrate: 16000,
            maxCallSignalingTimeoutMs: 30000
        });
        device.on('error', (device) => {
            console.log("error: ", device)
        });
        setState({... state, device, twilioToken, nickname})
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
};
```

However, I am not getting the error:

```
error:  ConnectionError: ConnectionError (53000): Raised whenever a signaling connection error occurs that is not covered by a more specific error code.
    at ConnectionError.TwilioError [as constructor] (twilioError.ts:48:1)
    at new ConnectionError (generated.ts:340:1)
    at PStream._handleTransportMessage (pstream.js:176:1)
    at WSTransport.emit (events.js:153:1)
    at WSTransport._this._onSocketMessage (wstransport.ts:453:1)
```

Comment: Where are you setting the `room_name` in the state?

Comment: @philnash Thanks, I updated my question with changes that I made to address that issue

Comment: Oh, ok. So you've fixed the `room_name` issue, now you don't have a `device` object? Where do you create the `device`?

Comment: @philnash I have included the code where I create the device object

Comment: Ok, your device is now available. A 53000 error is normally about connectivity. Can you maybe run through [this diagnostics app](https://video-diagnostics.twilio.com/) and see what it says. There's more explanation of the [diagnostics in this blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/video-diagnostics-app-reactjs-preflight-api).

Comment: @philnash everything seems to work well. Not sure if it's relevant/helpful but I'm using Twilio Conference API

Comment: It might help to create your Device with a more in depth logLevel. You can pass options to the Device when you create it and `logLevel: "trace"` would give you a lot more information. One other thing, you don't have to hit your `voice_chat/rooms` endpoint from your own application to start the conference. All you are doing is returning XML to your front-end, which doesn't need it. That endpoint should be used by Twilio, but not your front-end.